# Art or art forms

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "art" instead of "art form"?

1. "Music and dancing are absolutely art forms."
2. "Music and dancing are absolutely art."
3. "Photography is an art form."
4. "Photography is art."

Comment: Your use of ***absolutely*** (and synonymous ***totally***) in #1 and #2 is a bit "slangy", but apart from that there's nothing wrong with any of them (but in more formal contexts you might be better using something like ***definitely, unquestionably,*** or ***certainly*** for the first two).

Comment: Thank you. But regarding "an art form" and and "art"? Are all my sentences correct?

Comment: Yes - "there's nothing wrong with any of them". It would also be perfectly possible to use the article with just the unqualified noun: *Photography is **an art***. And you could include a straightforward adjective (as opposed to a noun used adjectivally) with or without that article: *Photography is [not] **high art**,  Photography is **visual art***.

Comment: You might find some relevant info in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116551/there-is-x-vs-there-is-a-an-x) that I asked on ELU some years ago regarding use of articles with certain "abstract nouns".

Answer (score 5):

**Yes,** *art* and *art form* can be interchangeable, though they aren't identical. *Art* can be used not just for types of artistic expression, but for individual works of art as well, whereas *art form* specifically refers to some kind of practice or medium of creating art.

For example:

Painting, photography, sculpting, and dancing are *art forms*.

A specific painting, photograph, sculpture, or dance routine is *art*.

Van Gogh's "Starry Night" is not an art form. But it is art.

All of your sentences are acceptable, as people do use "art" as a general term to refer to all things related to art, forms of art included. But as the other answer notes, it can be desirable to make the distinction anyway, with sentences 2. and 4. being less precise than sentences 1. and 3.

Comment: Picasso's "Les Demoiselles d’Avignon" is not an art form. But it is art. *And* it is ***an example of an art form*** (being the earliest artwork classified under "Cubism"). I'm not an art historian, so I don't know whether "Starry Night" would qualify as an example of an *identifiable, known and named* "art form" as with the Picasso.

Comment: If I am talking about a particular painter, should I use the article before "art"? For example, "I like art of Picasso" or "I like the art of Picasso."

Comment: @AntoniaA "I like the art of Picasso" is the grammatically correct choice between those two, but it doesn't sound entirely natural. In my experience, a more common way of phrasing it would be "I like Picasso's art."

Answer (score 2):

Your sentences are all grammatical, but 1 and 3 are better choices. "Art" has many different meanings, but one is "paintings" as in "art collector." Thus, 2 and, particularly 4, are somewhat confusing.

You could replace "art" with "arts" in sentence 2 and avoid that potential confusion. You could replace "art" with "an art" in sentence 4 and avoid that potential confusion.

In short, all four sentences are grammatical, but 2 and 4 are not **artfully** worded.

Comment: Some art collectors _do_ collect photographs.

Answer (score 0):

They're certainly all grammatical. However, in my opinion, the phrase "____ is [an] art" is almost a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase), and usually connotes a value judgment. See also: "But is it art?" and "This is art."

- Sculpture is an art form. *(Factual statement describing the meaning of the word "sculpture.")*
- Sculpture is an art. *(The speaker is judging the aesthetic worth of the sculptural arts, and finding sculpture to be aesthetically worthwhile.)*

On very close inspection, I also imagine a difference in focus: "Sculpture is an art form" seems to use the word "sculpture" to talk *only* about the medium, i.e. the end product (sculptures). "Sculpture is an art" seems to me to connote a little more about the *whole process*, including how to choose one's subject matter, how to compose and frame it, and so on. I might just be getting some bleed-over from how I would imagine the Wikipedia article might start: "Sculpture is **the art of** carving or modeling..." "Photography is **the art of** creating durable images by recording light..." which naturally frames the art as an ongoing mechanical and creative process.

Comment: So, to you, the phrase “art form” has no aesthetic dimension; it merely describes an activity with a physical result so we can say “Murder is an art form.”

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say _no aesthetic dimension_; but yes, to me, the sentence "Murder is an art form" connotes something slightly more physical in nature than the more abstract "Murder is an art" (which might include some tangentially related processes such as getting away with it, and so on, and the speaker might be looking down his nose at those who treat it as _merely_ the artful creation of physical artifacts such as dead bodies). The two sentences certainly are not _opposites_; I just claim that to me, they have slightly different connotations. (Perhaps analogous to "artisan" vs "artist"?)